# Fill SQL temp table from results AFTER execution of SPROC

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, refactoring

Is there a way to fill a temp table/other SQL variable **after** a SPROC has been executed?

I have the SQL results sitting in the SSMS results window, but I don't want to re-run the SPROC to fill a temp table because it takes over an hour.

I can export to CSV and re-import (using OPENROWSET, which is always difficult), but I was curious if there are any more elegant solutions?

I've run into this several times and have not found anything simple..

Comment: youd have to export to csv, then import to a new table. no good option here lol

Answer (score 0):

There's no way.

Also, watch out exporting from SSMS to CSV because 
a)It formats things (especially dates and numbers) and 
b)It truncates columns (43679 chars max, which might sound a lot but gets used up quickly if XML).

So your export might not be a true representation of results.